# pluma editor open document on a new instance

Tags: mate, pluma

I am using ubuntu mate 20.04. 
Whenever pluma is open and I want to edit another file it opens on a new tab on the already opened editor.
How can I force it to open on a new window instead?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/usr/share/applications/pluma.desktop`
 and change `Exec=pluma %U` 
to `Exec=pluma %U --new-window`

the solution was provided by [this forum](https://linux-user.gr/t/pluma-editor-force-new-instance/2126/2).